# What is the pythonic way to this dict to list conversion?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example, convert

```
d = {'a.b1': [1,2,3], 'a.b2': [3,2,1], 'b.a1': [2,2,2]}
```

to

```
l = [['a','b1',1,2,3], ['a','b2',3,2,1], ['b','a1',2,2,2]]
```

What I do now

```
l = []
for k,v in d.iteritems():
  a = k.split('.')
  a.extend(v)
  l.append(a)
```

is definitely not a pythonic way.

Comment: You could do `l.append(k.split('.') + v)`, but why is this transfer necessary?

Comment: @jonrsharpe To prepare data for functions which accept different types of inputs. The real data is much more complicated than this example.

Comment: But where's it coming from and where's it going to? Could you change one or the other to simplify the process?

Comment: The modules are not my code ....... One requires dict input and produces dict out, and the other asks for list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python 2:

```
d = {'a.b1': [1,2,3], 'a.b2': [3,2,1], 'b.a1': [2,2,2]}
l = [k.split('.') + v for k, v in d.iteritems()]
```

Python 3:

```
d = {'a.b1': [1,2,3], 'a.b2': [3,2,1], 'b.a1': [2,2,2]}
l = [k.split('.') + v for k, v in d.items()]
```

These are called [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
>>> d = {'a.b1': [1,2,3], 'a.b2': [3,2,1], 'b.a1': [2,2,2]}
>>> print([k.split(".") + v for k, v in d.items()])
[['b', 'a1', 2, 2, 2], ['a', 'b1', 1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b2', 3, 2, 1]]
```